# Redefining itemize environment for deeper nesting causes compilation to freeze

Tags: enumitem, pandoc

I'm trying to add some nesting levels to the standard `itemize` environment using `enumitem`. The idea is to add this to the `-H` argument so as to allow [`pandoc` to handle deeper itemized list nesting](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2922). Here's what I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize, 1]{label=\labelitemi, itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 2]{label=\labelitemii, itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 3]{label=\labelitemiii, itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 4]{label=\diamond, itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 5]{label=\smallblacksquare, itemindent=0.75em}
\setlist[itemize, 6]{label=\smalltriangleup, itemindent=1.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 7]{label=\smallcircle, itemindent=1.75em}
\setlist[itemize, 8]{label=\smallsquare, itemindent=2.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 9]{label=\labelitemiv, itemindent=3em}

\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \begin{itemize}
            \item test
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the compilation gets stuck on `(./test.aux)` and I don't know why. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It does not seem to have anything to do with the levels but more `\labelitemi`, the error is still present if you outcomment level configs for 2-9 and remove `\renewlist` and `\setlistdepth`. So it is the use of `\labelitemi` and friends that is causing the problem

Comment: The problem is probably that `enumitem` also want to define `\labelitemi` and this you end up in an infinite loop. Might be better to code the labels for level 1-3 manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As daleif already pointed out, you run into a loop, which you can prevent by saving the original label item definitions first:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\let\oldlabelitemi\labelitemi
\let\oldlabelitemii\labelitemii
\let\oldlabelitemiii\labelitemiii
\let\oldlabelitemiv\labelitemiv

\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize, 1]{label=\oldlabelitemi, itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 2]{label=\oldlabelitemii, itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 3]{label=\oldlabelitemiii, itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 4]{label=\diamond, itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 5]{label=\smallblacksquare, itemindent=0.75em}
\setlist[itemize, 6]{label=\smalltriangleup, itemindent=1.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 7]{label=\smallcircle, itemindent=1.75em}
\setlist[itemize, 8]{label=\smallsquare, itemindent=2.25em}
\setlist[itemize, 9]{label=\oldlabelitemiv, itemindent=3em}

\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item test
          \begin{itemize}
              \item test
          \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good, but if I go beyond a depth of 3 I now get a missing `$` error...

Comment: If your labels are mathematical symbols, you have to write e.g. `label=$\triangleleft$`